# ESRI JSON :Polygon is not Showing on the map

Tags: javascript, maps, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

My own coordinates not showing on the map.I am new to arcgis javascript maps.pleas help  me here.The code workinng fine with first object in the feature array in orchard.js file
with first map object in the index.html but not working with my own polygon coordinates

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>
<title>Geometry Engine Showcase</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.15/esri/css/esri.css">
<style>
html, body, #map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#results{
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 150px;
}
#title{
  top: 20px;
  width: 50%; 
  height: 50px;;
  padding-top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 0 0 25%;
}
.mainStyle{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 15px;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
</style>

<script>
var dojoConfig = { 
  paths: {
    data: location.pathname.replace(/\/[^/]+$/, "") + "/data"
  }
};
</script>

<script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.15/"></script>
<script>
var map, orchardLayer;
require(["esri/map",
         "esri/graphic",
         "esri/graphicsUtils",
         "esri/geometry/Extent",
         "esri/geometry/geometryEngine",
         "esri/geometry/Polyline",
         "esri/geometry/Point",
         "esri/SpatialReference",
         "esri/toolbars/draw",
         "esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol",
         "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol",
         "esri/symbols/TextSymbol",
         "esri/symbols/Font",
         "esri/Color",
         "esri/renderers/SimpleRenderer",
         "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer",
         "data/orchards",  //Feature layer representing an apple orchard
         "dojo/on",
         "dojo/_base/array",
         "dojo/dom",
         "dojo/domReady!"
], function(Map, Graphic, graphicsUtils, Extent, geometryEngine, Line, Point, SpatialReference, Draw, SimpleFillSymbol, SimpleLineSymbol, TextSymbol, Font, Color, SimpleRenderer, GraphicsLayer, orchards, on, array, dom) {
    
  var initExtent = new Extent(-13056650, 6077558, -13055709, 6077938, new SpatialReference({wkid:3857}));
    
  //Instructions for using the app. Will update based on user behavior    
  var drawInstructions = "Click outside the selected feature to begin drawing cutting line. Double-click to finish line and make final cut.";
  var initInstructions = "Click to select a feature.";
  var mergeInstructions = "Select another polygon to merge into the selected feature.";
  var addInstructions = "Click to begin drawing a new feature. Polygons must have at least 3 vertices.";
  var deleteInstructions = "Click to delete a feature.";
  dom.byId("instructions").innerHTML = initInstructions;

  //below map object comes  with default example working fine with first feature object in feature array

  // map = new Map("map", {
  //   basemap: "satellite",
  //   extent: initExtent
  // });

    //My custom map configration setting centre,map is showing but my own polygon rings 
second object in the features array is not showing 

  map = new Map("map", {
    basemap: "streets",
    center: [77.019135, 28.481216],
    zoom: 9,
    showAttribution:true
  });
    
  //Layer symbology    
  var orchardSym = new SimpleFillSymbol(SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, new Color([175, 255, 155]), 2), new Color([175, 255, 155, 0.3]));
  var selectionSym = new SimpleFillSymbol(SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_NULL, new Color("black"), 3), new Color([255, 255, 255, 0.25]));
  var offsetSym = new SimpleFillSymbol(SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_NULL, new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_DASH, new Color("#960AC4"), 2), new Color([96, 252, 219, 0.5]));
  var cutterSym = new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_DASH, new Color("white"), 2);
  var renderer = new SimpleRenderer(orchardSym);
    
  //Get FeatureLayer created from FeatureCollection stored on the client through data/orchards
  orchardLayer = orchards;  
  orchardLayer.setRenderer(renderer);
    
  //Create graphics layer for labeling
  var displayLabels = new GraphicsLayer();
  var labelFont = new Font(14, Font.STYLE_NORMAL, Font.VARIANT_NORMAL, Font.WEIGHT_BOLD, "Verdana");    
  var textSym = new TextSymbol("filler text", labelFont, new Color("white")).setHaloColor(new Color("#960AC4")).setHaloSize(2);
    
  //Create selection layer to display selection symbol
  var selectionLayer = new GraphicsLayer();
  var originalGraphicSelection, selectedGraphic;

  //Create GraphicsLayer for cutting line   
  var cutGraphic1, cutGraphic2;

  map.addLayers([orchardLayer, selectionLayer, displayLabels]);
    
  //Initialize Draw polygon tool
  var drawPolygon = new Draw(map, { showTooltips: true });
  drawPolygon.setFillSymbol(new SimpleFillSymbol(SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, cutterSym, new Color([255, 255, 255, 0.25])));
 
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map">    
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my data/orchard.js file whiere i am getting my polygon json to render on map

```
define(["esri/layers/FeatureLayer"], function (FeatureLayer) {
    var orchardJson = {
        "objectIdFieldName": "OBJECTID",
        "globalIdFieldName": "",
        "geometryType": "esriGeometryPolygon",
        "spatialReference": { "wkid": 102100, "latestWkid": 3857 },
        "fields": [{ "name": "OBJECTID", "type": "esriFieldTypeOID", "alias": "OBJECTID", "sqlType": "sqlTypeOther", "domain": null, "defaultValue": null },
         { "name": "NAME", "type": "esriFieldTypeString", "alias": "NAME", "sqlType": "sqlTypeOther", "length": 100, "domain": null, "defaultValue": null },
         { "name": "AREA", "type": "esriFieldTypeString", "alias": "AREA", "sqlType": "sqlTypeOther", "length": 100, "domain": null, "defaultValue": null },
          { "name": "GlobalID", "type": "esriFieldTypeGlobalID", "alias": "GlobalID", "sqlType": "sqlTypeOther", "length": 38, "domain": null, "defaultValue": null }],
           "features": [
               //working fine with there coordinates
               {
            "attributes": { "OBJECTID": 6, "NAME": "apple", "AREA": "calculate this",
             "GlobalID": "eb9337a3-0edd-48c7-9acf-0151c4310153" },
            "geometry": {
                "rings":
                    [
                        [
                        [-13056478.2271, 6077897.9925], 
                        [-13055890.7646, 6077901.4887], 
                        [-13055886.5869, 6077768.2201], 
                        [-13055887.8402, 6077728.532], 
                        [-13055891.6001, 6077703.048], 
                        [-13055898.2845, 6077680.4885], 
                        [-13055905.8043, 6077665.031], 
                        [-13055914.5775, 6077652.4979], 
                        [-13055926.275, 6077637.876], 
                        [-13055949.2524, 6077620.7474],
                         [-13055975.5719, 6077609.0499], 
                         [-13056000.2203, 6077603.2011], 
                         [-13056034.8952, 6077601.53], 
                         [-13056099.6495, 6077602.3655],
                          [-13056165.5846, 6077601.3813],
                           [-13056282.6647, 6077601.3813], 
                           [-13056473.7252, 6077604.773],
                            [-13056478.2271, 6077897.9925]
                        ]
                    ]
            }
        },
        //My own coordinates not showing on map
        {
            
                        "attributes": { "OBJECTID": 6,
                         "NAME": "test 1", 
                         "AREA": "calculate this",
                        // "REGION":"Test",
            },
            'geometry': {
              'rings': 
              [
                [
                  [ 77.15760062500001,30.890967638580772],
                  [ 77.2941240625,29.57600861486909],
                  [ 76.95873343750002,28.428848818170273],
                 [ 75.9202178125,28.434726060930952],
                 [ 75.5131084375,28.909133164756486],
                 [ 74.70792777343749,29.39857793541408],
                 [ 74.78873587890624,29.871326311523653],
                 [ 75.48477835937497,29.65680741133687],
                 [ 76.15957328125,29.79063051517841],
                 [ 77.15760062500001,30.890967638580772],
                ],
              ],
            },
          },
    ]
    };

    var layerDef = {
        "geometryType": orchardJson.geometryType,
        "fields": orchardJson.fields,
        "spatialReference": orchardJson.spatialReference
    };

    var orchards = new FeatureLayer({
        layerDefinition: layerDef,
        featureSet: orchardJson
    }, {
        mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_SNAPSHOT
    });

    return orchards;
});
```

Comment: The problem is that your coordinates are not in WebMercator, (WKID 3857), check the difference between the numbers. Yours seems to be Geographics coordinates (WKID 4326), so you need unify your layer, Web Mercator or Geographics.

Comment: Thank you so much @cabesuon.This works fine after changing it to Geographics coordinates (WKID 4326).

Comment: Glad you solve it!